# Excel IF nested condition with 3 variables

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, macros

I have 3 columns, Low, Medium and High with numbers in them. I need another column to compare the numbers such as IF(AND(number in Lcolumn>number in High column,number in Lcolumn>number in Medium column), "Low".

So I need the cell to both identify the highest number in the row (be it in either low, med or high column) and then label it accordingly. Is this possible?
Thanks

EDit: if numbers are the same I would need the final product labelled Medium/High or Low/Medium

Comment: what if some or all the numbers are the same ?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want the new column to have the name of the column with the highest value (its a little confusing that the column names are High, Medium and Low, so that "Low can be the highest value, as in your example.)

You can accomplish this using the Max function to find the highest value, and then test this against each of the values you are interested in comparing.

Example: Assume High, Medium and Low are in columns A, B, C, respectively.  Then the following would work as the formula in the fourth column. (Example for Row two of spreadsheet)

```
If(Max($A2,$B2,$C2)=$A2,"High",If(Max($A2,$B2,$C2)=$B2,"Medium","Low"))
```

EDIT: Noticed your edit re the label you want if numbers are equal.  That's incorporated here.  These conditions can obviously be worked into the above logic by replacing "High" and "Low" with some additional IF statements.